# How to Deliver Javascript files from NPM on an Intranet Application with No Access to the Internet/CDNs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently attempting our first go at using a .NET Core web application on our Intranet. Most tutorials I go through are showing that in production, files can only be served from the wwwroot and to use CDNs for production. However, the server this application will be hosted on does not have access to the internet, and therefore will not be able to access any CDNs. In the past for regular .net applications we've just been able to publish the NPM loaded packages and serve them up from there. How can I mimic this same behavior in MVC core, knowing that every client library we use will need to be loaded from the web application itself and not a CDN?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Hmmmphh. Somehow missed that documentation. Okay, setting up a runner on the build server then to run npm install during the build task should get me where I want.

Comment: I never use CDNs for production for all of our applications. I mainly use `npm` to grab any client-side libraries to the hidden node_modules folder, use `Bundlers & Minifiers` along with `Web Compiler` from Mads Kristensen to bundle files I need to the wwwroot folder. I also need to use `gulp` to move files other than javascript files and css files to the wwwroot, such as fonts, images, etc. And then when published, we publish to a folder first where all needed packages should be downloaded, and then move to the production server. We never check in wwwroot folder by the way.

Comment: Perhaps not an answer to your question, but I can recommend [Libman](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs). You can target any online/offline library and select the files you need.